# In how many ways can can 12 different books be distributed among 3 students if each student receives at least 2 books?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

My teachers gave me a similar question (but in that there were 8 different books):

So we make 2 cases- $(2,2,4)$ or $(2,3,3)$

Then, we solve using formula of distributing $n$ distinct objects into 3 persons such that they have $x,y,z$ objects (irrespective of order) i.e $$\frac{n!}{(x!\cdot y!\cdot z!)}$$

How will we solve, if there were 12 books instead of 8?

Comment: Let $~\overline{(a,b,c)}~$ represent all of the possible permutations of the ordered triple $~(a,b,c).~$ Assuming that the three students are distinguishable, consider the cases $~\overline{(2,2,8)}, ~\overline{(2,3,7)}, ~\overline{(2,4,6)}, ~\overline{(2,5,5)},~$ then continue by also considering $~\overline{(3,3,6)}, ~\overline{(3,4,5)}, ~\overline{(4,4,4)}.~$ At this point, the issue is not whether a more elegant approach presents itself.  Instead, the issue is, how are you supposed to use the mathematical tool (i.e. previous example) given to you by your teacher?

Comment: When we have n distinct objects and we need to divide them into 3 groups having x,y,z objects then we use this formula to find the number of ways in which this can be done.In this question as we have persons which are distinct we will rearrange them by 3!.

Comment: There would be $3^{12}$ ways to distribute the books if there were no restrictions.  You could use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to remove those distributions in which a student receives no books or only one book.

Answer (score 1):

the multinomial coefficient $ \frac{n!}{x!\cdot y!\cdot z!}$ respects the order i.e there is allways the first student (say Ann), the second student (say Bob) and the third one.

If this is the case, we have to enumerate the possible incomes for each student

$$ egf_1 (x) = {x^2 \over 2!}  + {x^3 \over 3!} + \cdots + {x^{12} \over 12!}  $$

take their "entangled product"

$$ egf_A (x) . egf_B (x) . egf_3 (x) $$

then read the coefficient of $${x^{12} \over 12!}  $$ which is $445896$.

If the students are anynomous, the involved structures are rather partitions than ballots. We have to partition 12 different books into three parts, each of a size larger than 2.

Hard to avoid, the combinatorial description of such a structure via combinatorial species/classes is

$$ Ens_3 (Ens_{2+}) $$

***a 3-set of sets larger than 2***

$$ egf (x) = {1\over 3!} ( {x^2 \over 2!}  + {x^3 \over 3!} + \cdots + {x^{12} \over 12!} )^3 $$

The requested coefficient will be now $74316$ which equates $445896 \over 3!$

This proportionality by 3! is explained like this

Starting from partitions : take for example {A,B}, {C,D,E} and {F, G, H} a "good" partition of 8 books.
Now, we easily build a ballot by allocating a specified student to each chunk, in exactly 3! possible ways.

The 3! here is the amount of bijections from a 3-set to a 3-set.